# Create new dataframe column with values based existing column AND on dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
smsgateway = {'AT&T':'@txt.att.net', 'Boost Mobile':'@sms.myboostmobile.com', 'Cricket':'@sms.cricketwireless.net', 'Google Fi':'@msg.fi.google.com', 'Metro PCS':'@mymetropcs.com', 'Republic Wireless':'@textrepublicwireless.com', 'Sprint':'@messaging.sprintpcs.com', 'T-Mobile':'@tmomail.net', 'U.S. Cellular': '@email.uscc.net', 'Verizon':'@vtext.com', 'Virgin Mobile': '@vmobil.com', 'XFinity Mobile':'@vtext.com'}
```

and I have a dataframe like so:

```
Name         cell_provider  cell_number
Tony Danza   Google Fi      9999999999  
John Smith   T-Mobile       8888888888
```

Ultimately, I am trying to create a new df column that is created based on the cell_number and the cell_provider (9999999999@msg.fi.google.com) but I am stuck at trying to create a column that is taking the elements of cell_provider and comparing them to the key/value pair of the smsgateway dictionary. I understand how to concat the columns after I get past this step, could anyone point me in the right direction? Please...and THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `cell_provider` values with the addresses from the dictionary using `.replace` and then add the resulting series to the cell number after casting to string like this:

```
df = df.assign(cell_num_provider=df.cell_number.astype(str) + df.cell_provider.replace(smsgateway))
```

output:

```
   cell_number cell_provider           cell_num_provider
0     99999999     Google Fi  99999999@msg.fi.google.com
1     88888888      T-Mobile        88888888@tmomail.net
```

See documentation on [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

Comment: You guys are geniuses! It amazes me how simple these fixes can be and how much more I have to learn still...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to the first answer. you could use transform:

```
df['address'] = df['cell_number'].astype(str) + df['cell_provider'].transform(lambda: smsgateway[x])
```

output:

```
      cell_number  cell_provider    address
0     99999999     Google Fi        99999999@msg.fi.google.com
1     88888888     T-Mobile         88888888@tmomail.net
```

Comment: You guys are geniuses! It amazes me how simple these fixes can be and how much more I have to learn still... Thank you as well!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest way would be to use map:

```
df['cell_num_provider'] = df.cell_number+df.cell_provider.map(smsgateway))
```

|  | Name | cell_provider | cell_number | cell_num_provider |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tony Danza | Google Fi | 9999999999 | 9999999999@msg.fi.google.com |
| 1 | John Smith | T-Mobile | 8888888888 | 8888888888@tmomail.net |

Comment: This looks great too! Thanks! What is the etiquette for selecting an answer!?

Comment: You can select the tick mark on the left side of answer below votes buttons to mark it as accepted answer. Detailed instructions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow#:~:text=Click%20the%20green%20outlined%20checkmark,%22has%20an%20accepted%20answer%22.